# calculating shortest grid distance

Tags: java, grid, distance

> Consider a city where the streets are perfectly laid out to form an infinite square grid. In this city finding the shortest path between two given points (an origin and a destination) is much easier than in other more complex cities. As a new Uber developer, you are tasked to create an algorithm that does this calculation.
>
> Given user's departure and destination coordinates, each of them located on some street, find the length of the shortest route between them assuming that cars can only move along the streets. You are guaranteed that at least one of the coordinates is an integer.

I am struggling a little to figure out the logic here. There are many cases and I don't know how to accommodate them all. This is what I have so far

```
double perfectCity(double[] departure, double[] destination) {
    double yDist = Math.abs(destination[1]-departure[1]);
    double xDist = Math.abs(departure[1] - departure[0] + departure[1]-destination[0]);
    return xDist + yDist;
}
```

Comment: the input isn't very clear, how are the origin and destination represented?

Comment: It's going to be quite difficult to come up with **any** algorithm that can cope with this stipulation: "an **infinite** square grid".

Comment: Don't use an array for that. Use `double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2`. Or create a class `Point`, and give it an `x` and `y` field.

Comment: Can you show some inputs and outputs that don't have integers? It will make the question much clearer.

Comment: You need Dijkstra and Manhattan distance in your solution.  Is this an interview or homework question?

Comment: @duffymo Dijkstra will be overkill for this. Since the city blocks are all squares, the solution can just use geometry to reason out the solution. It's an O(1) operation if done properly.

Comment: Dijkstra is about reasoning your way to shortest path.  I think Manhattan distance is the right way to calculate path weights. No need to invent something new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The algorithm is very simple if the inputs are integers, just find the absolute value between the x and y coordinates and then add them together. This is called the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).

```
int distance = Math.abs(x1 - x2) + Math.abs(y1 - y2);
```

With doubles, it is almost exactly the same, except for one situation. Here are some possibilities:

1. Both points have integer coordinates
2. One point has integer coordinates, and the other point has only one integer coordinate
3. Both points have only one integer coordinate, but they are on different axes.
4. Both points have only one integer coordinate, and they are on the same axis.

Possibilities 1-3 all work fine using the same algorithm as for finding distance with integers, except #4 has the possibility of the axis in common being on the same block.

For example, if the inputs were: `{x: 0.5, y: 2}` and `{x: 0.5, y: 3}` you would have to travel horizontally, vertically, and then backwards horizontally again in order to reach the destination. This is different from inputs of `{x: 0.5, y: 2}` and `{x: 1.5, y: 3}` because there is no need to travel backwards on the same axis.

So you can use the normal algorithm in all cases *except* for the case of when both of the Xs or Ys have floating-point values and have the same `floor`-ed value.

Your code should look something like this.

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public static double perfectCity(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    double xDist = abs(x1 - x2);
    double yDist = abs(y1 - y2);
    if (floor(x1) != x1 && floor(x2) != x2 &&        // both Xs are doubles
        floor(x1) == floor(x2) &&                    // on the same block
        y1 != y2) {                                  // not on the same street
        xDist = min(abs(x1 - floor(x1) + x2 - floor(x2)),
                    abs(x1 - ceil(x1)  + x2 - ceil(x2)));
    } else if (floor(y1) != y1 && floor(y2) != y2 && // both Ys are doubles
               floor(y1) == floor(y2) &&             // on the same block
               x1 != x2) {                           // not on the same street
        yDist = min(abs(y1 - floor(y1) + y2 - floor(y2)),
                    abs(y1 - ceil(y1)  + y2 - ceil(y2)));
    }
    return xDist + yDist;
}
```

This can be much further simplified by using a helper function to calculate each axis separately.

```
public static double perfectCity(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    return travelOnAxis(x1, x2, y1 == y2) + travelOnAxis(y1, y2, x1 == x2);
}

private static double travelOnAxis(double from, double to, boolean travelIsStraight) {
    if (Math.floor(from) == Math.floor(to) && !travelIsStraight) {
        double dist = Math.abs((from % 1) + (to % 1));
        return Math.min(dist, 2 - dist);
    } else {
        return Math.abs(from - to);
    }
}
```

I used the trick with `2 - dist` here because it's the same as calculating

```
Math.abs((1 - (from % 1)) + (1 - (to % 1)))
```

which is the same as

```
Math.abs(from - Math.ceil(from) + to - Math.ceil(to))
```

Comment: Thanks for solution and explanation, In the simplified solution what is the reason behind using 2 - dist @ `Math.min(dist, 2-dist)`?

Comment: @Monkey Your comment made me reevaluate the algorithm, and I found a flaw.  I need to make an adjustment for when the input is something like `(0, 0.2) -> (0, 0.3)`. Currently this code outputs `0.5` as the answer, when it should be `0.1`. I'll fix the algorithm, then I'll explain the `2 - dist` trick.

Comment: @MonkeyD.Luffy I have now updated my answer. Thanks anna

Answer (score 1):

If this is a square grid, you can consider the x and y coordinates separately; the minimum distance is the sum of the minumum distances in the two directions.

In the `p`-direction (either `x` or `y`), you have to move from `p1` to `p2`. From `p1`, you can either move to `floor(p1)` or `ceil(p1)` to get to a road (which may be equal, if `p1` is an integer); from there, you can move to either `floor(p2)` or `ceil(p2)`, the road on which `p2` is located; from there, you can move to `p2`.

So, the minimum distance in the `p`-direction is

```
min(abs(p1 - ceil(p1) ) + abs(ceil(p1)  - floor(p2)) + abs(floor(p2) - p2),  # (1)
    abs(p1 - floor(p1)) + abs(floor(p1) - ceil(p2) ) + abs(ceil(p2)  - p2),  # (2)
    abs(p1 - floor(p1)) + abs(floor(p1) - floor(p2)) + abs(floor(p2) - p2),  # (3)
    abs(p1 - ceil(p1) ) + abs(ceil(p1)  - ceil(p2) ) + abs(ceil(p2)  - p2))  # (4)
```

So you can just calculate this independently for the `x` and `y` directions, and add.

---

To illustrate this (abbreviating `floor` and `ceil` as `f` and `p` respectively):

```
f(p1) p1  c(p1)
  +---O>>>>+>>>>>>>>+
                    .
                    .
                    +>>>O----+
                  f(p2) p2  c(p2)

--------------------------------> p axis
```

The shortest route is indicated here with `>`. The `.`s are on the shortest route, but since that part of the route is orthogonal to the `p` direction, it "doesn't count" towards the minimum distance in that direction.

The minimum route shown here, `p1 -> c(p1) -> f(p2) -> p2`, is Case 1 above.

It should not be hard to visualize swapping `p1` and `p2`, in which case the minimum route is to go from `p1 ->f(p1) -> c(p2) -> p2` (Case 2).

The case of `pN == f(pN) == c(pN)` is not very different; then, the part of the expression `abs(pN - f(pN))` or `abs(pN - c(pN))` is just zero.

The slightly different case is where `f(p1) == f(p2)`:

```
f(p1) p1  c(p1)          f(p1) p1  c(p1)
  +---O>>>>+               +<<<O----+
           .               .
           .               .
  +-----O<<+               +>>>>>O--+
 f(p2) p2  c(p2)          f(p2) p2  c(p2)

--------------------------------> p axis
```

In this case, the minimum route can either be `p1 -> f(p1) -> f(p2) -> p2` or `p1 -> c(p1) -> c(p2) -> p2` (which are Cases 3 and 4, respectively).

Comment: `Math.min` can only take 2 parameters, so it would have to be chained together. I'm surprised at how similar out answers are! I just split off the Case 3 & 4 into the `if` statements.

Comment: I didn't say anything about this being implemented using `java.lang.Math`, or even Java really. It's just a general expression.

Comment: Ahh, well I wouldn't have known that from the syntax and the context.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by 4castle, the problem is trivial if only integers are considered for input. You would never have to "move back" after having "moved forward" in that case since you would always reach your destinaton in a single move.

But since, **at most** one floating point number needs to be considered for each of departure/destination, we need to consider 3 cases, (**warning: lengthy explanation**). Below is a python2 implementation with explanations.

1. x co-ordinates of both departure and destination are the same and are **not** floating point numbers. In this case, the shortest distance is simply the absolute difference between y co-ordinates. The same logic applies vice-versa.

   ```
   import math
   class Location():
       def __init__(self, cord):
           self.x = cord[0]
           self.y = cord[1]

   def perfectCity(departure, destination):
       l1 = Location(departure)
       l2 = Location(destination)

       if l1.x == l2.x and float(l1.x).is_integer() and float(l2.x).is_integer():
           return abs(l1.y-l2.y)
       if l1.y == l2.y and float(l1.y).is_integer() and float(l2.y).is_integer():
           return abs(l1.x-l2.x)
   ```
2. When one of the co-ordinates in the *departure* is a floating point, then:

   - If x co-ordinate is floating point, we can move backwards(round down) or move front(round up).
   - If y co-ordinate is floating point, we can either move down (round down) or move up (round up).
   - The above logic should work even when there is no floating point co-ordinate since we move in either direction by **zero**  units.
   - Once we calculate these, we just choose the minimum among those like below,

`return min(calc_round_up_dist(l1, l2), cal_round_down_dist(l1, l2))`

`Lets take an example of (0.4, 1) and (0.9, 3)` for below calculations.

3. While calculating the round_up we need to calculate 3 distances:

   - round_up_distance: difference between the rounded up value of the floating point co-ordinate and the original floating point co-ordinate. We return **zero** if there is no floating point co-ordinate. `1 - 0.4 = 0.6 in the above example`
   - non_floating_point difference: difference between the non floating point co-ordinate of departure and the corresponding co-ordinate of destination ( **note that this might be floating point or not a floating point** `abs(3-1) = 2 in the above example`
   - Difference between departure's floating point counterpart in the destination co-ordinate `0.9 in the above case` and the new value of departure's floating point after rounding up, `0.4 + 0.6(this is the round_up distance) = 1.0`, i.e. `abs(0.9 - 1.0) = 0.1`
   - Adding all the 3 above we get `0.6 + 2 + .1 = 2.7` which is the shortest distance.
   - Corresponding calculation needs to be done for rounding down. And we pick the minimum among both. The code for round_up and round_down is as below,

     ```
     import math
     class Location():
         def __init__(self, cord):
             self.x = cord[0]
             self.y = cord[1]

         def floating_point_round_up(self):
             if not float(self.x).is_integer():
                 return math.ceil(self.x) - self.x
             if not float(self.y).is_integer():
                 return math.ceil(self.y) - self.y
             return 0

         def floating_point_round_down(self):
             if not float(self.x).is_integer():
                 return self.x - math.floor(self.x)
             if not float(self.y).is_integer():
                 return self.y - math.floor(self.y)
             return 0

         def non_floating_point_diff(self, obj):
             if not float(self.x).is_integer():
                 return abs(self.y - obj.y)
             if not float(self.y).is_integer():
                 return abs(self.x - obj.x)
             return abs(self.y - obj.y)

         def floating_point_counterpart(self, obj):
             if not float(self.x).is_integer():
                 return obj.x
             if not float(self.y).is_integer():
                 return obj.y
             return obj.x

         def floating_point(self):
             if not float(self.x).is_integer():
                 return self.x
             if not float(self.y).is_integer():
                 return self.y
             return self.x
     ```
4. Round up and down functions are as below,

   ```
   def calc_round_up_dist(l1, l2):
       dist = l1.floating_point_round_up()
       diff = l1.non_floating_point_diff(l2)
       floating_point_counterpart = l1.floating_point_counterpart(l2)
       new_val = dist + l1.floating_point()
       return dist + diff + abs(new_val - floating_point_counterpart)

   def cal_round_down_dist(l1, l2):
       dist = l1.floating_point_round_down()
       diff = l1.non_floating_point_diff(l2)
       floating_point_counterpart = l1.floating_point_counterpart(l2)
       new_val = l1.floating_point() - dist
       return dist + diff + abs(floating_point_counterpart - new_val)
   ```
5. Finally the main function that calls the above methods,

   ```
   def perfectCity(departure, destination):
       l1 = Location(departure)
       l2 = Location(destination)

       if l1.x == l2.x and float(l1.x).is_integer() and float(l2.x).is_integer():
           return abs(l1.y-l2.y)
       if l1.y == l2.y and float(l1.y).is_integer() and float(l2.y).is_integer():
           return abs(l1.x-l2.x)

       return min(calc_round_up_dist(l1, l2), cal_round_down_dist(l1, l2))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is a practice question on CodeSignal:
https://app.codesignal.com/company-challenges/uber/gsjPcfsuNavxhsQQ7

```py
def solution(departure, destination):
    # go to the closest integer
    # I can only travel the path of an integer
    # if the number is a float I need to travel to an integer first
    # then travel to the destination

    x1, y1 = departure
    x2, y2 = destination
    res = 0
    
    # check if the coordinations are integers
    a = list(map(isInteger, departure))
    b = list(map(isInteger, destination))
    
    # if all are integers or if the corresponding elements are different
    if a[0] ^ b[0] or (a[0] and a[1] and b[0] and b[1]):
        return abs(x1-x2) + abs(y1-y2)
        
    if a[0]:
        res += abs(x2-x1)
        # cloest distance from y1 to y2
        res += getClosest(y1, y2)
    else:
        res += abs(y2-y1)
        # closes distance from x1 to x2
        res += getClosest(x1, x2)
    
    return res
    
def getClosest(y1, y2):
    cand1 = math.floor(y1)
    cand2 = math.ceil(y1)
    # find the integer closer to y1 to move to
    res1 = abs(y1-cand1) + abs(cand1-y2)
    res2 = abs(y1-cand2) + abs(cand2-y2)
    return min(res1, res2)
    
def isInteger(n):
    return n == round(n)
```